# Lua : recursive multiple numbers GCD Euclide calculation -- everlasting loop

Tags: recursion, lua

I try to calculate recusively the GCD of several numbers.

Here my try. with more than numbers two is an erverlasting loop.
I'm not sure about the `pgcd( unpack(arg))` part, but I have no idea of something else.

**Edit** In fact, it seems to be the `arg.n >2` that is not efficient...

```
function pgcd ( ... )
    local arg = table.pack(...)
    if arg.n >2
    then
        local tmp = table.remove(arg,1) 
        return pgcd (tmp, pgcd( unpack(arg) ))
    else
        a,b = unpack(arg)
        repeat
        a , b = b , a % b
        until a % b == 0
        return b
    end
end


print (pgcd(18,12))  -- works fine


print (pgcd(18,12,9)) -- everlasting loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the endding test was testing once too far.

```
function pgcd ( ... )
    local arg = table.pack(...)
    if arg.n > 2
    then
        local tmp = table.remove(arg,1)
        return pgcd (tmp, pgcd( unpack(arg) ) )
    else
        a,b = unpack(arg)
        repeat
        a , b = b , math.fmod(a,b)
        until b == 0 -- test was once too far
        return a
    end
end


print (pgcd(18,12))  -- works fine

print (pgcd(18,12,6)) -- works fine
```